# haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml not working

Tags: java, xml, opencv

I am currently working on a java project on face detection. I am using  OpenCV API opencv_310 available at the official site and started writing the program following
[this tutorial](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/nui07/index.html)

But the main problem is that this tutorial was written more than five years ago. So the OpenCV APIs and working procedures have changed over the years. So I encountered a problem regarding the file ***haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml***.

`new CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad(FACE_CASCADE_PATH));`

This line of code throws the following exception:

> OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?)) in cvRead, file ........\opencv\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp, line 4991
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: ........\opencv\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp:4991: error: (-2) The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?) in function cvRead

So I browsed the Internet for a while and found [this](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/246). It says the old C API does not support the newer haarcascade format. It also suggests to try with the C++ API.

What should I do now? I don't know how to try the C++ API. It will be highly appreciable if you can give some instructions on how to deal with the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html) which is from opencv site. This has a link to the source code. The xml file which you have trouble is the trained data.. if you would like to just download this file, you can find it [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades)
regards